# How to: update rootViewController IOS 13 SceneDelegate

Tags: swift, ios13

Setting the rootViewController in the app state is keeping a nil value. I am working in the scene delegate building for ios 13.

Instantiating the view controller is done here `guard let signIn = Storyboards.signIn.instantiateInitialViewController() as? SignInViewController else { break }`

From here the value of signIn is nil - even with a breakpoint showing a sucessfull instantiation.

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.setWithRippleTransition(rootViewController: signIn)
state.rootViewController = signIn
```

Answer (score 0):

The SceneDelegate.swift was interfering with the lines above setting the apps rootViewController. Soultion was to set the rootViews there...

```
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SignIn", bundle: nil)
  let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController (withIdentifier: "signIn") as! SignInViewController
  firstVC = vc
```